# Left-align numbers in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, chapters, line-numbering

How do I lelft-align the chapter and section, number in the ToC? My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A}
\section{One section}
\addtocounter{section}{9}
\section{Other section}

\addtocounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{B}
\section{Hello}
\addtocounter{section}{9}
\section{Next}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and I want

```
 1.1 One section
1.11 Ohter section
```

and the same for chapters.

Comment: You can also look at a solution given by egreg that does not use tocloft http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252570/9255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is based on example code given on pp. 11-12 of the user guide of the `tocloft` manual; I've just replaced `X` with `sec` and `chap`, respectively. Feel free to adjust the initial values of `\mylenchap` and `\mylensec` to suit your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlength\mylensec
\setlength{\mylensec}{0.75em}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\hspace*{\mylensec}}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{\mylensec}

\newlength\mylenchap
\setlength{\mylenchap}{1em}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{\hspace*{\mylenchap}}
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\mylenchap}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A}
\section{One section}
\addtocounter{section}{9}
\section{Another section}

\addtocounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{B}
\section{Hello}
\addtocounter{section}{9}
\section{Next}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to align left the number of chapters and not to the right as in sections?

Comment: @CarlosE - Absolutely: Just delete (or comment out) the instructions from `\newlength\mylensec` to `\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{\mylensec}`.